# What is the application of combinatorial game theory

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, gt.game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I find Combinatorial Game Theory very interesting as my primary interest is mathematics. My question is why do Computer Scientists (who tend to have a more practical approach) study it as well? Are there some applications of it? This question is similar to this [one](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16187/applications-of-game-theory-in-computer-science) but I am asking about combinatorial games such as nim. Could someone provide me with a reference?

Comment: A vague guess is that applications are more in AI than "theory" as we usually think of it...

Comment: You seem to assume that computer scientists study a topic mainly because it has applications, which is false.

Comment: Indeed, one of the first books in combinatorial game theory (*Surreal Numbers* by Knuth) explicitly *praises* its lack of applications.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think Kaveh's comment is the correct answer: applications? We don't need no applications.

But despite all that, combinatorial game theory does appear to have some applications in error correcting codes. See Conway and Sloane, "Lexicographic codes: Error-correcting codes from game theory", IEEE Trans. Inf. Th. 1986.

More simply, if you are willing to think of nim-addition (bitwise exclusive or) as something that came out of combinatorial game theory, then there are plenty of applications, for instance in [tabulation hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabulation_hashing), or as one of the components of Schieber and Vishkin's lowest common ancestors data structure, or as one of the components of some block cipher systems.

Comment: Nim-addition gives a nice definition of exclusive or that does not depend on binary representation. It is introduced only with a game involving natural numbers in mind, no binary required.

Comment: But, isn't considering biwise XOR as something that came out of CGT, a bit far fetched? Anyway, I like your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find an application of combinatorial game theory in cryptography. See the link [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.2.2928&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Combinatorial game theory and topics thereof has received a lot of attention in modelling and verification of reactive systems. I would draw your attention to [this](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs6860/2010fa/Handouts/thomas.pdf) nice reference for more information.

Comment: Which combinatorial games have  you got in mind?